# How to interpret different socket tester results with and without power strip?

Tags: reverse-polarity, socket

I bought a socket tester ([this one](http://www.habo-test.com/sale-11598410-ht106-110-220-volt-outlet-tester-wall-socket-tester-for-voltage-measurement.html)) in order to check the power sockets in the house I rent. Half of them seem to be correct and the other half is marked as "LIVE/NEU REVERSE" which is not that good, as far as I understand.

One of those "LIVE/NEU REVERSE" sockets has a power strip plugged into it. It's a new power strip with ground connections and I've decided to check its sockets with the same device, just out of curiosity. To my surprise, the device marked all of the power strip sockets as correct.

What does it mean? Is it possible that power strip detects "LIVE/NEU REVERSE" state and corrects it automatically? If so, does it really fix the problem and make this socket safe to use?

UPDATE: I tried it with "correct" socket and now the power strip is marked as "LIVE/NEU REVERSE".

Comment: What happens when you plug the power strip into a socket that doesn't have line and neutral reversed?

Comment: You don't have a DMM?

Comment: @k-h I just tried it with "correct" socket and now the power strip is marked as "LIVE/NEU REVERSE"

Comment: @tony-stewart-sunnyskyguy-ee75 no, I don't have it and have no idea how to use it. Just trying to figure out should I be concerned about that reverse polarity situation

Comment: Which type of sockets you have? Which country is this, and which way the local electrical code says the L and N should be?

Comment: @Justme Type B, Thailand

Comment: @Justme I also found this: "the standard building code in Thailand, the U.S. and other places is that with the ground on the bottom center, the top left is neutral and the top right is "load" or alternating voltage (110 to 220)"

Comment: Both the power strip and part of the house wiring are reported as faulty by the tester. In that case it's reasonable to ask if you can trust the tester. A really good one will be calibrated to standards traceable to a national laboratory : a cheap one can be tested against a good one (if you can find one). If in doubt, take it to a reliable local electrician.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the sockets in your house and also your portable power strip have line/neutral reversal problems in the wiring.  Switching the wires twice switches them back.  You might want to get an electrician to check all of your wiring, or if you're willing to do enough research and it's legal in your area, fix it yourself.  You can't just go around matching same color wires though so if it turns out the problem is more complicated than just the plugs being connected wrong, it would be wise to hire a professional.

Line/Neutral reversal is a sadly common problem.  It can go unnoticed almost indefinitely, but it's better to correct and may be a sign of other bad practices.  Most device power switches switch the line wire, and if line and neutral are reversed, parts of a device could be unexpectedly energized even if the load is turned off and shock someone.  This is also a reason best practice is to have switches consistently on the line side.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I'll contact the house owner.